# i am trying to get the alert when 2 conditions meet on different or same candles

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator, pine-script-v4

basically my main issue is if condition_1 show Long signal on one candle so loop or something else will start and when condition_2 show long signal on the same or other candle then it will give me an alert

i use this script and it will work fine and will show an alert when both conditions give signal on the same candle
`alertcondition(bsignal == true and long == true, title="Buy", message="Buy")`

but it never gives an alert when both conditions show signal on different candle, so i need to know that  what to add in script to show an alert if 2 conditions give signal on different candle ...?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to check if `bsignal` was `true` in the past X bars (for example up to 5 bars ago). If so, you can use `ta.barssince()` function, which counts the number of bars since the last time a condition was `true`. For example you can use:

```
cond = ta.barssince(bsignal) < 5 and long
alertcondition(cond, title="Buy", message="Buy")
```